# Unable to run YCSB successfully for ElasticSearch

Tags: nosql, elasticsearch, benchmarking, ycsb

I am new to both YCSB and ElasticSearch. I was able to run YCSB easily for Cassandra. However, I have not been able to do the same with ES (or perhaps I have but I am not sure).

Following the steps documented in YCSB/elasticsearch, I was able to start the test and I even got the results. I am not sure on which ES instance is it running on? For Cassandra, I had to start the Cassandra Server myself and then run the tests (providing the hosts details along with the ycsb command). ES, on the other hand, does not require us to do anything of that sort. So how does YCSB run these tests. I didn't even have my local ES instance up but the tests gave results.

Any insights would really help?

Thanks!